# Solve $(...)[0] is undefined error

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, scroll

I'm trying to get the scroll height of a div box by returning the DOM element itself, using the native scrollHeight property.

```
Long scrollHeight = (Long) jse.executeScript("return $(\"//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/ul\")[0].scrollHeight");
```

However, I got this error **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $(...)[0] is undefined**. How can I go about solving this?

**Web page eg** https://www.instagram.com/p/_HQyf0iY9L/

I don't want to use the className of the div box as this is just one of the website I will want to get the scrollheight from. The className will differ from various web pages.

Comment: This is happening because your selector is bringing nothing, which element do you want to pick with this selector?

Comment: @RodrigoLeite I want to pick a div box with this selector

Comment: can you share the link to web page?

Comment: @drets please see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert xpath selector to css selector:

```java
Long scrollHeight = (Long) jse.executeScript("return $('#react-root ul')[0].scrollHeight");
```

Comment: This error came out instead **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $x is not defined**

Comment: After adding the import for browser, there's this error **incompatible types: int cannot be converted to JavascriptExecutor**

Comment: Use your code implementation - change only argument of `executeScript` method